# How to use a column as the color dimension when drawing with plotly.graph_objects.Scatter?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, visualization

I've been able to easily use a column as the color variable when drawing with plotly express, but struggled to do the same thing with plotly.graph_objects.Scatter. Also, all the lines are connected, how to separate them?

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x_values = range(1, 11)
y_values = ['a', 'b', 'c']

xs, ys, zs = [], [], []

for y in y_values:
    for x in x_values:
        #print(x, y)
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)
        zs.append(np.random.rand())
d = pd.DataFrame({'x': xs, 'y': ys, 'z': zs})

px.line(d, x='x', y='z', color='y')


fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(
    x=d['x'],
    y=d['y'],
    mode='lines'
))

fig.show()
```

EDIT:
I understand we can use different traces for the lines, but I'm really looking to replicate what Plotly Express can do.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you should transform your `df` long to wide, as example with `pd.pivot_table` and add a trace for every column you need.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x_values = list(range(1, 11))
y_values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x_values*len(y_values),
                   "y":np.repeat(y_values,len(x_values)),
                   "z":np.random.rand(len(x_values)*len(y_values))})

# px.line(df, x='x', y='z', color='y')

# long 2 wide
pv = pd.pivot_table(df,
                    index = "x",
                    columns="y",
                    values = "z")\
       .reset_index()

fig = go.Figure()
for col in pv.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=pv['x'],
        y=pv[col],
        mode='lines',
        name=col
    ))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rpanai. Can this be done in an automatic fashion? Since I'm using this in an interactive visualization, and the traces could be many and also will change based on user input. Ideally, I can replicate what Plotly Express does.